# How to verify custom domain for email template?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]

I am trying to verify domain for email template in firebase.
it keep failing for a week now.

Please help me. TIA

Comment: I'd recommend checking if all the DNS records that Firebase requires you to add are propagated using [DNSChecker](https://dnschecker.org/)

Comment: This is also a problem better suited to directly contacting [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/hosting/dns/help)